# Feature engineering with non-fixed length vectors?

Tags: machine-learning, svm

I have a bunch of data that looks like this:

```
[
[[3,1,4], [6,5,22], [1,-4,77]], # Observation One
[[595,4,-3], [-123,3,9], [44,41,97], [12,-44,194]], # Observation Two
[[-4,99,-22]] # Observation Three
...
]
```

So - in general, each observation is composed of vectors that are size 3. Each observation does not have a fixed length.

Basically, I have a bunch of observations that are not of the same length. I don't know how I would throw this at a standard machine learning classification algorithm.

I had an idea of computing the pairwise distance matrix and re-scaling that to a fixed dimension as an input feature. This idea was inspired by image classification.

Does anyone have any advice for me on how I could create a good fixed-length feature vector representation?

Comment: Steven, welcome to cross validated. My guess is that your question cannot be answered unless you tell us more about your application and also what type of measurements you have.

Comment: Hey cbeleites, these are actually protein models of varying lengths. Each sub-vector represents the geometric position of the atom. I'm not sure whether there was a standard way to do pre-process this type of data in stats/ml to be a fixed vector format.

Comment: Maybe you could look into QSAR/QSPR literature how they set up their features. I don't have any experience in that field, so this is just a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Rational kernels which are based on weighted finite-state transducers (WFST) are designed to extend the SVM approach for varied-length sequences.